# Is there a way of making multiline comments in Scilab?

Tags: comments, scilab

I am new to Scilab and I am trying to make a multi-line comment. Accessing the documentation, they only say this about comments:

[image]

Source: https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.3.3/en_US/comments.html

Apparently, there is no way of making a multi-line comment. However, it is hard to believe, at least for me, that the authors of the language didn't think about this feature. Does any body know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily comment whole code blocks by highlighting (one or) more lines and then press `Ctrl+D` or from the menu: Format > Comment Selection. This will place the `//` at the beginnig of every line automaticallay.

To uncomment something, highlight it, then `Ctrl+Shift+D`, or Format > Uncomment Selection menu.

Comment: This is a very misleading answer! OP has asked for multi-line comments, not how comment several lines at once in Scilab editor!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that multiple lines comments were introduced in Scilab 6.0.0.

[From the manual](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/comments.html):

> Another way to comment a block of code is to use /* at the beginning and */ at the end.

Comment: Unfortunately this great feature is yet to be seen on ScicosLab line of development. I have tried to email them so far no response :(